# Changing the DPI of Inkscape’s PNG export

Tags: inkscape, export, svg, dpi, dimensions

I use Inkscape and want to export a PNG image (of my SVG file) with dimensions 1080 px by 1920 px. However the DPI is always set to 90 and if changed, the dimensions change with it. Is it possible to have a higher DPI with the same dimensions?

Comment: I don't use Inkscape so I'm not sure but I know at one point (it's possibly changed now) the ppi of an export was always stuck at 90ppi. Is there a specific reason you need to change the ppi?

Comment: I just wanted the resolution/clarity (I don't really know the term XD) to increase without the height and width (1080by1920px) of the image being changed. @Cai

Comment: the *only* thing that affects clarity is the pixel dimensions. Resolution (as in DPI or PPI) is only meta data, it doesn't actually affect your image at all.

Comment: On Linux, when exporting to `.PNG`,  I find that the DPI affects the clarity of the image, whereas the image size is unaffected by change of DPI.  I use the PNG image in a Latex document.

Answer (score 4):

1) If you want a file 1920x1080 px, the ppi is TOTALLY irrelevant, because you want it for an electronic medium.

2) In the case of the export focus on the pixel size. Yes, on the moment of the export, the ppi and the dimensions are intertwined but after that, you can change that in gimp or another aplication like IrfanView.

3) You could try to change the dimensions before exporting, but there is no point in doing so.

Answer (score 4):

Inkscape 1.0 supports this now here...

```
File → Export PNG image → Advanced → pHYs dpi setting
```

[image: Inkscape export PNG dialog]

Answer (score 2):

**No, you can't.**

In Inkscape, DPI box on the Export window refers to actual pixels. and you can't decouple it from pixel size.  The fact that the option is on the export window has always confused me (and probably lots of other people).

It looks like you can get the results you are looking for [by increasing the document size](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=11864#p64382), but I wouldn't bother.

What you want to do is export to the desired pixel size, and **ignore the DPI setting in Inkscape**. After you've exported, open up the image in a Raster editor, like Gimp, and change the pixel size. In Gimp, the option is under *Image > Print Size*.

As others have pointed out, the DPI is just metadata.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can control the dpi but it will change the actual size of the image.[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that if is changed it to let's say 100 dpi, the dimensions will change?

Comment: If you know the dimensions in inches and the DPI you want, then you can calculate the dimensions in pixels. If you know the dimensions in pixels, there is no need to calculate the DPI. As already said, it is irrelevant. The answer by @Raphael explains it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have the "Custom" tab selected at the top of the Export PNG Image area. Change that to "Page" if you're using the page border guide or "Selection" if you want to export individual selections.

Comment: Welcome. I know that you have low reputation and therefore you can not comment, but this is more a comment than an answer, do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

@moon is this export option available on the command line? I am using
inkscape --export-type="png" foo.svg foo.png and I want a 300ppi 150x150 png

I *do* want a precise ppi and size when I edit in photoshop, ideally without a second update routine